# SqlLocalDB 2014 can not find SqlUserInstance.dll

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-localdb

Everytime I run the command: `SqlLocalDB` i get this error: `SqlUserInstance.dll not found! Windows error code: 126.`

I searched but I could not find anything on what to do. I repaired the SqlLocalDatabase 2014 express but that didnt help either

EDIT: I just took a look and its under: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn`

Comment: did you do the actual install of LocalDB on this server, or just copy the files there? If you just copied the executable or a folder from another machine, you likely do not have the registry entry / entries that point to the install path. That is probably what it is looking for.